# Does nativescript have http2 support?

Tags: nativescript

I'd like to understand whether http2 is supported with the current http nativescript library?
I understand that nsurlsession for iOS supports http2 but I'm not sure how it works for Android. I do know that okhttp supports http2.

Is anybody using http2 with nativescript?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use https://www.npmjs.com/package/http2?

Disclaimer: I've never tried it yet myself in nativescript